# TCP server with Python: How to optimize my implementation?

Tags: python, tcp, network-programming, ethernet

I would like to implement a TCP server using a Python script.

The server should basically do the following task:

It will be cyclically polled by a remote client, then reads certain data on its local workstation and sends it to the client polling.

One can assume the following:

- There is always only one client connecting to the server (via Ethernet)
- Client and server are running on a Windows platform
- Python 2.5.1 will be used for implementation

Goal:

- The server should be as efficient as possible with respect to reading/writing data from/to the client
- The server shall stress the local workstation as less as possible
- The server shall not cause system instability

Since I have only a little experience with the topic, I would like to discuss here how my current (very simple) code could be optimized to meet the requirements previously mentioned.

So far I have the following:

```
import socket
import sys

port_number = 12345
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server_address = (socket.gethostname(), port_number)
sock.bind(server_address)

sock.listen(1)
while True:
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    try:
        while True:
            data = connection.recv(4096)
            if data:
                connection.sendall(getdesireddata(data))
            else:
                break
    finally:
        connection.close()
```

Thank you for all your responses.

Comment: Next week, Python 2.5.1 will turn six years old.  I guess it will still work until the sun burns out, but still you ought to at least use a slightly more modern version to get the thousands of bugfixes since then.

Comment: @JohnZwinck The real question is why he is not using [`SocketServer.TCPServer`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5/lib/module-SocketServer.html)...

Comment: You can try using an asynchronous framework, like Twisted (or other of the many: Tornado. etc.) Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: I would also prefere upgrading Python but this has to be decided by someone else

Comment: @Bakuriu: It is because I can not upgrade to Python 2.6

Comment: TCPServer is already present in python2.5(in fact the link points to python2.5 documentation)

Comment: @ypercube: What would be the main benefit of such a framework? As fara as I know there are mainly used for communication via Internet or multi-threading. Additionally, I would like to avoid to install new Python packages because I think that the server I need is quite simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there's minor bug in the code. The line...

```
data = connection.recv(4096)
```

...will attempt to read up to 4k from a single TCP packet, but if the client sends more than 4k, or decides to break up the data into several packets, you may not get all the data in a single call.

You'd typically continue to read data from the socket, appending to a buffer, until either you have a complete message as defined by your protocol specification, or until the remote host closes the outbound half of its TCP connection.

You'll also have issues with the server getting stuck if the client crashes, and doesn't shut down the socket properly. To avoid this, you'll need to look at either non-blocking IO, which would be something like...

```
connection.setblocking(0)
buffer = ''
while 1:        
    try:
        data = connection.recv(4096)
        if not data:
            # Client has closed outbound connection
            break
        else:
            # Append to buffer
            buffer += data
    except socket.error, e:
        code = e.args[0]
        if code == 11:
            # Got EWOULDBLOCK/EAGAIN
            time.sleep(0.1)
        else:
            # Got another error
            raise
do_something_with(buffer)
```

...or look at using the Python [select](http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html) module to do the same thing.

With regards to the lesser concern of performance, I don't see any major improvements you can make with such a small code sample.

Comment: Thank you for your response and the explanation of this bug.

The server is intended to run all the time (from system boot up to system shut down). However, is there still the possibility that the current server will stuck and not respond properly to client requests?

Comment: TBH, writing networking code which is tolerant of all the possible edge cases associated with the TCP/IP protocol is a complete pain in the butt. It might be worth taking a look at other (well-commented) implementations of TCP socket servers for some clues. One obvious thing is to allow the server to cope with multiple concurrent connections, in case one of them gets stuck somehow. Also, try testing what happens if you yank out a network cable while a connection is established, and see how well it copes with subsequent connections when you plug it back it.

Comment: Thanks again for that. Would SocketServer.TCPServer make sure that all the data are received in a single call or does the server also need to continue reading data from the socket until it has the complete message (as you mentioned in the example above)?

Comment: No. `TCPServer` just exposes two file-like objects for reading and writing respectively. Point is, there's no generic way to when you have a complete message because it depends on the protocol. For example, in keepalive HTTP POST, the client will send a `Content-Length` header so the server knows when it's read the complete message body.

Comment: I understand. Does TCPServer has any other advantages (for my use case) comparing to the code above so that I should change my code to use it?

Comment: TBH, I'm not really that familiar with it, but it's existed for a long time, so it will have been well tested. Why not read its source code and decide for yourself?

Comment: One more thing I would like to know is the following. If the client polls the server let's say every 20 ms: Should the client then create a new connection for every single poll operation, which will be closed after the server has send the data for that single poll operation or should one connection be created which remains open as long as the client polls the server (a couple of hours)?

Comment: Probably safer to create a new connection each time. Poorly configured routers love to reset inactive TCP connections.